# How to resize slider(control-field) inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

In a very simple example

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}], {{a, 1}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

I would like to resize the size of the control-field to get smaller slider size.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: `ImageSize -> Tiny` next to `Appearance`?

Comment: @Kuba How easy, thanks! And for a list of parameters I have to do it step by step ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, π}], 
  {{a, 1}, 0, 5, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Although it isn't what you asked, I think this is a much better solution:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, π}], {{a, 1}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 ControlType -> VerticalSlider]
```

[image]

Comment: VerticalSlider does not have the + checkbox allowing to see the numerical value.

Comment: @PierreALBAREDE:  Mine shows the numerical value.  See addition to solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot the `Appearance -> "Labeled"`, thank you,